# How To handle result set of websql in html 5?

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I m creating mobile web application using html5 and javascript.I m having two javascript files. AttributesDatabase.js and AttributeView.js.From AttributeView.js i m calling one function from AttributeDatabase.js in that i m executing one select query.Now the query result should go to AtttributeView.js.But the Websql transaction is asynchronous call that is what it is not returning proper result.Is there any way to handle the websql result.
Please help if any way there?

**Edited**

```
AttributeView.js

var AttributeDAOObj = new AttributeDAO();

AttributeDAOObj.GetAttributeList();
alert(AttributeDAOObj.GetAttributeList());  //This alert is coming as undefined.   

AttributeDAO.js
this.GetAttributeList = function () {
    var baseDAOObj = new BaseDAO();
    var query = "SELECT AttributeName FROM LOGS";
    //  this.Successcalbackfromsrc = this.myInstance.Successcalback;
    var parm = { 'query': query, 'Successcalback': this.myInstance.Successcalback };
    baseDAOObj.executeSql(parm);
}

//To Create database and execute sql queries.
function BaseDAO() {
this.myInstance = this;
//Creating database
this.GetMobileWebDB = function () {
    if (dbName == null) {
        var dbName = 'ABC';
    }
    var objMobileWebDB = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", dbName, 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    return objMobileWebDB;
}

//Executing queries and getting result 
this.executeSql = function (query) {
    var objMobileWebDB = this.myInstance.GetMobileWebDB();
    objMobileWebDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
 //In this transaction i m returning the result.The result value is coming.
        transaction.executeSql(query, [], function (transaction, result) { return result; }, this.Errorclback);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you posted some code

Comment: You don't return results from an asynchronous operation, you call callbacks when the results arrive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you succes call back (like in the comment to your question, stated by DCoder)

```
 function (transaction, result) { return result; }
```

this is returning where to?

So this is how to do it (or at least one way)

you can do for example:

```
function (transaction,result){
   console.log("yes, I have some result, but this doesn't say anything, empty result gives also a result");
   // so check if there is a result:
    if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
       if (result.rows.length == 0) {
            // do something if there is no result
       }else{
            for ( var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = result.rows.item(i);
                var id = result.rows.item(i).id; //supposing there is an id in your result
                console.log('Yeah! row id = '+id);
            }
        }
    }else{
       // do something if there is no result
    }
};
```

note the code above can be compacter, but this is how to understand it better.

another way is to put this function is a seperate piece of code, so you keep the sql statement more compact and readable. Like you call you error callback this can be in your function (with this. in front of it) or a completely seperate function.